# How to control dew condensation when shooting tracks in a diffusion fog box?

Tags: experimental-physics, home-experiment, condensation

I got dry ice, so I made a diffusion fog and tried to shoot the track. So I created a diffusion fog box with the following steps:

1. I prepared a circular plastic container with a radius of 6 cm.
2. Next, a sponge soaked with ethanol was attached to the top of the container.
3. I made a few mm hole in the container and put in the α-ray source.
4. I warmed the top of the container by hand.
5. I touched the bottom of the container with dry ice finely crushed with a mixer to create a temperature gradient.

With this, the alpha ray track was successfully observed. However, I had a problem when I took the picture.

When I have a camera trying to shoot a track from the top of the container, the top of the container becomes cloudy and I often wipe the container and miss the timing of the shoot.

Also, I have confirmed that fixing and wiping the camera does not solve the problem as it will fog too quickly.

Although I don't have sophisticated machinery to regulate the temperature, what do I do to avoid fogging of the container?

Comment: A later higher scored version of this question has answers: ["Condensation on the side of a cloud chamber"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/763282/145491).